# What are my options for installing software on a remote PC?

Tags: windows, installation

I get a lot of requests to install programs (mainly exe, some MSI) on remote PCs, currently I have to ask the user to logoff and then use a remote control app to logon and install the program, this is OK but users are telling me that I'm not getting round to them quick enough, they basically find a program and say I want this installed this afternoon. Is there a way to run the setup on my PC but target theirs so they don't need to be interupted?

PS Windows XP and Windows 7 are in use.

Thanks
S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a system management solution. Those (amongst other things) can deploy software to client computers.

In a Windows environment, the ideal choice would be Microsoft's [System Center Configuration Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/configurationmanager/en/us/default.aspx) (also known as SCCM), but there are of course lots of other available solutions.

Be aware, though, that those are enterprise-grade products, and are usually priced accordingly.

If you need to deploy MSI packages, you can also use Active Directory GPOs; they're quite limited in what they can do, but can be very useful.

Comment: +1,  SCCM sounds perfect, except that he also sounds like its not an enterprise where there are standards in place to prevent a user from needing, then getting upset that software isn't installed in the same day.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to work with your management to set an SLA, or at least informally set expectations. Same-day software installation isn't realistic in some (maybe even most) environments.

Comment: Seconded; sounds like your users are in the habit of treating you like a doormat!  I'd also recommend starting to say "no", especially to the more unreasonable requests.  Customer service doesn't mean saying "yes" to everything after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to remotely execute commands on user machines. Usually, you can execute [msiexec.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759262%28WS.10%29.aspx) command-line tool with some options like /qn for silent install.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using WSUS Package Publisher (https://wsuspackagepublisher.codeplex.com/) to push applications and updates to clients. They install through the Windows Update system.
And it's free!

You need to have a running WSUS Server with SSL enabled.